# advantage of tap method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was just reading a blog article and noticed that the author used `tap` in a snippet something like:

```ruby
user = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.username = "foobar"
  u.save!
end
```

My question is what exactly is the benefit or advantage of using `tap`? Couldn't I just do:

```ruby
user = User.new
user.username = "foobar"
user.save!
```

or better yet:

```ruby
user = User.create! username: "foobar"
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

When readers encounter:

```
user = User.new
user.username = "foobar"
user.save!
```

they would have to follow all the three lines and then recognize that it is just creating an instance named `user`.

If it were:

```
user = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.username = "foobar"
  u.save!
end
```

then that would be immediately clear. A reader would not have to read what is inside the block to know that an instance `user` is created.

Answer (score 47):

This can be useful with **debugging a series of `ActiveRecord` chained scopes.**

```
User
  .active                      .tap { |users| puts "Users so far: #{users.size}" } 
  .non_admin                   .tap { |users| puts "Users so far: #{users.size}" }
  .at_least_years_old(25)      .tap { |users| puts "Users so far: #{users.size}" }
  .residing_in('USA')
```

This makes it super easy to debug at any point in the chain without having to store anything in in a local variable nor requiring much altering of the original code.

---

And lastly, use it as a **quick and unobtrusive way to debug without disrupting normal code execution**:

```
def rockwell_retro_encabulate
  provide_inverse_reactive_current
  synchronize_cardinal_graham_meters
  @result.tap(&method(:puts))
  # Will debug `@result` just before returning it.
end
```

Answer (score 44):

Another case to use tap is to make manipulation on object before returning it.

So instead of this:

```
def some_method
  ...
  some_object.serialize
  some_object
end
```

we can save extra line:

```
def some_method
  ...
  some_object.tap{ |o| o.serialize }
end
```

In some situation this technique can save more then one line and make code more compact.

Answer (score 32):

Using tap, as the blogger did, is simply a convenience method. It may have been overkill in your example, but in cases where you'd want to do a bunch of things with the user, tap can arguably provide a cleaner looking interface. So, perhaps it may be better in an example as follows:

```
user = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.build_profile
  u.process_credit_card
  u.ship_out_item
  u.send_email_confirmation
  u.blahblahyougetmypoint
end
```

Using the above makes it easy to quickly see that all those methods are grouped together in that they all refer to the same object (the user in this example). The alternative would be:

```
user = User.new
user.build_profile
user.process_credit_card
user.ship_out_item
user.send_email_confirmation
user.blahblahyougetmypoint
```

Again, this is debatable - but the case can be made that the second version looks a little messier, and takes a little more human parsing to see that all the methods are being called on the same object.

Answer (score 19):

If you wanted to return the user after setting the username you'd need to do

```
user = User.new
user.username = 'foobar'
user
```

With `tap` you could save that awkward return

```
User.new.tap do |user|
  user.username = 'foobar'
end
```

Answer (score 15):

It results in less-cluttered code as the scope of variable is limited only to the part where it is really needed.  Also, the indentation within the block makes the code more readable by keeping relevant code together.

[Description of `tap` says](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap):

> **Yields self to the block, and then returns self.** The primary purpose
>   of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform
>   operations on intermediate results within the chain.

If we [search rails source code for `tap` usage](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?p=3&q=tap&utf8=%E2%9C%93), we can find some interesting usages.  Below are few items (not exhaustive list) that will give us few ideas on how to use them:

1. Append an element to an array based on certain conditions

   ```
   %w(
   annotations
   ...
   routes
   tmp
   ).tap { |arr|
     arr << 'statistics' if Rake.application.current_scope.empty?
   }.each do |task|
     ...
   end
   ```
2. Initializing an array and returning it

   ```
   [].tap do |msg|
     msg << "EXPLAIN for: #{sql}"
     ...
     msg << connection.explain(sql, bind)
   end.join("\n")
   ```
3. As syntactic sugar to make code more readable - One can say, in below example, use of variables `hash` and `server` makes the intent of code clearer.

   ```
   def select(*args, &block)
       dup.tap { |hash| hash.select!(*args, &block) }
   end
   ```
4. Initialize/invoke methods on newly created objects.

   ```
   Rails::Server.new.tap do |server|
      require APP_PATH
      Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
      server.start
   end
   ```

   Below is an example from test file

   ```
   @pirate = Pirate.new.tap do |pirate|
     pirate.catchphrase = "Don't call me!"
     pirate.birds_attributes = [{:name => 'Bird1'},{:name => 'Bird2'}]
     pirate.save!
   end
   ```
5. To act on the result of a `yield` call without having to use a temporary variable.

   ```
   yield.tap do |rendered_partial|
     collection_cache.write(key, rendered_partial, cache_options)
   end
   ```

Answer (score 14):

Visualize your example within a function

```
def make_user(name)
  user = User.new
  user.username = name
  user.save!
end
```

There is a big maintenance risk with that approach, basically **the implicit return value**.

In that code you do depend on `save!` returning the saved user. But if you use a different duck (or your current one evolves) you might get other stuff like a completion status report. Therefore changes to the duck might break the code, something that would not happen if you ensure the return value with a plain `user` or use tap.

I have seen accidents like this quite often, specially with functions where the return value is normally not used except for one dark buggy corner.

The implicit return value tends to be one of those things where newbies tend to break things adding new code after the last line without noticing the effect. They do not see what the above code really means:

```
def make_user(name)
  user = User.new
  user.username = name
  return user.save!       # notice something different now?
end
```

Answer (score 11):

A variation on @sawa's answer:

As already noted, using `tap` helps figuring out the intent of your code (while not necessarily making it more compact).

The following two functions are equally long, but in the first one you have to read through the end to figure out why I initialized an empty Hash at the beginning.

```
def tapping1
  # setting up a hash
  h = {}
  # working on it
  h[:one] = 1
  h[:two] = 2
  # returning the hash
  h
end
```

Here, on the other hand, you know right from the start that the hash being initialized will be the block's output (and, in this case, the function's return value).

```
def tapping2
  # a hash will be returned at the end of this block;
  # all work will occur inside
  Hash.new.tap do |h|
    h[:one] = 1
    h[:two] = 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

It’s a helper for call chaining. It passes its object into the given block and, after the block finishes, returns the object:

```
an_object.tap do |o|
  # do stuff with an_object, which is in o #
end  ===> an_object
```

The benefit is that tap always returns the object it’s called on, even if the block returns some other result. Thus you can insert a tap block into the middle of an existing method pipeline without breaking the flow.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that there is no advantage to using `tap`. The only potential benefit, as [@sawa points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493604/373522) is, and I quote: "A reader would not have to read what is inside the block to know that an instance user is created." However, at that point the argument can be made that if you're doing non-simplistic record creation logic, your intent would be better communicated by extracting that logic into its own method.

I hold to the opinion that `tap` is an unnecessary burden on the readability of the code, and could be done without, or substituted with a better technique, like [Extract Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

While `tap` is a convenience method, it's also personal preference. Give `tap` a try. Then write some code without using tap, see if you like one way over another.

Answer (score 6):

There is a tool called [flog](https://github.com/seattlerb/flog) that measures how difficult it is to read a method. "The higher the score, the more pain the code is in."

```
def with_tap
  user = User.new.tap do |u|
    u.username = "foobar"
    u.save!
  end
end

def without_tap
  user = User.new
  user.username = "foobar"
  user.save!
end

def using_create
  user = User.create! username: "foobar"
end
```

and according  on flog's result the method with `tap` is the most difficult to read (and I agree with it)

```
 4.5: main#with_tap                    temp.rb:1-4
 2.4:   assignment
 1.3:   save!
 1.3:   new
 1.1:   branch
 1.1:   tap

 3.1: main#without_tap                 temp.rb:8-11
 2.2:   assignment
 1.1:   new
 1.1:   save!

 1.6: main#using_create                temp.rb:14-16
 1.1:   assignment
 1.1:   create!
```

Answer (score 4):

There could be number of uses and places where we may be able to use `tap`. So far I have only found following 2 uses of `tap`.

1) The primary purpose of this method is to **tap into** a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain. i.e

```
(1..10).tap { |x| puts "original: #{x.inspect}" }.to_a.
    tap    { |x| puts "array: #{x.inspect}" }.
    select { |x| x%2 == 0 }.
    tap    { |x| puts "evens: #{x.inspect}" }.
    map    { |x| x*x }.
    tap    { |x| puts "squares: #{x.inspect}" }
```

2) Did you ever find yourself calling a method on some object, and the return value not being what you wanted it to? Maybe you wanted to add an arbitrary value to a set of parameters stored in a hash. You update it with **Hash.[]**, but you get back **bar** instead of the params hash, so you have to return it explicitly. i.e

```
def update_params(params)
  params[:foo] = 'bar'
  params
end
```

In order to overcome this situation here, `tap` method comes into play. Just call it on the object, then pass tap a block with the code that you wanted to run. The object will be yielded to the block, then be returned. i.e

```
def update_params(params)
  params.tap {|p| p[:foo] = 'bar' }
end
```

There are dozens of other use cases, try finding them yourself :)

**Source:**
1) [API Dock Object tap](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap)
2) [five-ruby-methods-you-should-be-using](https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/five-ruby-methods-you-should-be-using)

Answer (score 3):

You're right: the use of `tap` in your example is kind of pointless and probably less clean than your alternatives.

As Rebitzele notes, `tap` is just a convenience method, often used to create a shorter reference to the current object.

One good use case for `tap` is for debugging: you can modify the object, print the current state, then continue modifying the object in the same block. See here for example: http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/eavesdropping-on-expressions.

I occasionally like to use `tap` inside methods to conditionally return early while returning the current object otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your codes more modular using tap, and can achieve a better management of local variables. For example, in the following code, you don't need to assign a local variable to the newly created object, in the scope of the method. Note that the block variable, *u*, is scoped within the block. It is actually one of the beauties of ruby code.

```
def a_method
  ...
  name = "foobar"
  ...
  return User.new.tap do |u|
    u.username = name
    u.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails we can use `tap` to whitelist parameters explicitly:

```
def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name).tap do |whitelist|
        whitelist[:name] = params[:client][:name]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give another example which I have used. I have a method user_params which returns the params needed to save for the user (this is a Rails project)

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :email,
    :address_attributes
  )
end
```

You can see I dont return anything but ruby return the output of the last line.

Then, after sometime, I needed to add a new attribute conditionally. So, I changed it to something like this:

```
def user_params 
  u_params = params.require(:user).permit(
    :first_name, 
    :last_name, 
    :email,
    :address_attributes
  )
  u_params[:time_zone] = address_timezone if u_params[:address_attributes]
  u_params
end
```

Here we can use tap to remove the local variable and remove the return:

```
def user_params 
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :first_name, 
    :last_name, 
    :email,
    :address_attributes
  ).tap do |u_params|
    u_params[:time_zone] = address_timezone if u_params[:address_attributes]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the world where functional programming pattern is becoming a best practice (https://maryrosecook.com/blog/post/a-practical-introduction-to-functional-programming), you can see `tap`, as a `map` on a single value, indeed, to modify your data on a transformation chain.

```
transformed_array = array.map(&:first_transformation).map(&:second_transformation)

transformed_value = item.tap(&:first_transformation).tap(&:second_transformation)
```

No need to declare `item` multiple times here.

Answer (score 0):

### What is the difference?

The difference in terms of *code readability* is purely stylistic.

### Code Walk through:

```
user = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.username = "foobar"
  u.save!
end
```

Key points:

- Notice how the `u` variable is now used as block parameter?
- After the block is done, the `user` variable should now point to a User ( with a username: ‘foobar’, and who is also saved).
- It's just pleasant and easier to read.

### API Documentation

Here’s an easy to read version of the source code:

```
class Object
  def tap
    yield self
    self
  end
end
```

For more info, see these links:

https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answers, I have used tap in stubbing and mocking while writing RSpecs.

Scenario: When I have a complex query to stub and mock with multiple arguments which shouldn't go missed. The alternative here is to use `receive_message_chain` (but it lacks the details).

```
# Query
Product
  .joins(:bill)
  .where("products.availability = ?", 1)
  .where("bills.status = ?", "paid")
  .select("products.id", "bills.amount")
  .first
```

```
# RSpecs

product_double = double('product')

expect(Product).to receive(:joins).with(:bill).and_return(product_double.tap do |product_scope|
  expect(product_scope).to receive(:where).with("products.availability = ?", 1).and_return(product_scope)
  expect(product_scope).to receive(:where).with("bills.status = ?", "paid").and_return(product_scope)
  expect(product_scope).to receive(:select).with("products.id", "bills.amount").and_return(product_scope)
  expect(product_scope).to receive(:first).and_return({ id: 1, amount: 100 })
end)

# Alternative way by using `receive_message_chain`
expect(Product).to receive_message_chain(:joins, :where, :where, :select).and_return({ id: 1, amount: 100 })
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use it for variable assignment such as-

```
@variable_name = []
  array.each do |item|
    @variable_name << {
      product: { id: item.id, price: item.price },
      status: 'Active',
      updated_at: item.updated_at,
      ...
    }
  end
@variable_name
```

Above can be achieve with tap such as-

```
[].each do |item|
    item << {
      product: { id: item.id, price: item.price },
      status: 'Active',
      updated_at: item.updated_at,
      ...
    }
  end
```

Hope will work for you!!!