# what ruby tap method does on a {}

Tags: ruby, tap

I've read about what tap does in Ruby but I'm confused by the code block below,

```
{}.tap do |h|
  # some hash processing
end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`#tap` method simply passes an object it was called on to a block. At the end of the block it returns the same object again. This way you can chain operations or restrict variable scope.

```
{}.tap { |h| h[:a] = 1 }.size # => 1
```

You were able to chain a next method to this block. And also avoided creating a `h` variable in your scope.

Comment: Note that `symbolize_keys` is only available through Rails, not in regular Ruby. It also seems unnecessary in your example so perhaps just rewrite it to `h[:a] = 1` if you want a symbol key.

Comment: You are right, that was for the sake of showing method chaining, of course

Answer (score 18):

`tap` is particularyl useful if you want to do some modifications on the hash and after that return it, e.g. inside a method that returns the hash. The advantage of `tap` being that you don't have to explitely return the hash at the end and there's no need for an intermediary variable.

```
hash = {}
hash[:a] = 'b'
hash
# => {:a=>"b"}
```

vs.

```
{}.tap do |hash|
  hash[:a] = 'b'
end
# => {:a=>"b"}
```

Comment: But is there any point in using tap over using `{ :a => :b }` or `{ a: :b }` explicitly?
UPD: Ah, I have found a usage - you can use key-value pairs defined first in later key-value pairs' definition, like this: `{}.tap { |hash|  hash[:a] = 'b'; hash[:c] = hash[:b] +  'd' }`

Answer (score 5):

For exemple : you want to chain delete and each on a hash.

You cannot do

```
hash.delete(:key).each {...}
```

but can do

```
hash.tap { |h| h.delete(:key) }.each { ... }
```

It is a good way to chain your methods.

Answer (score 2):

`tap` doesn't do anything to it. Whatever you do to `h` in the block is whatever is done to the original `{}`.