# why use tap method here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following Rails code,

```
root.join('lib', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
  config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
  config.assets.paths << bower_path
end
```

I am wondering why we need to use tap here

why not just use

```
bower_path = root.join('lib', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s
config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
config.assets.paths << bower_path
```

what's the benefit of using tap?

Comment: It is a matter of preference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [advantage of tap method in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493080/advantage-of-tap-method-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

One benefit might be that `tap` returns the object on which it was called. Your second versions is not exactly the same as the `tap` version. It is identical to:

```
bower_path = root.join('lib', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s
config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
config.assets.paths << bower_path
bower_path
```

It depends on the context if this feature is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I don't see any benefit.

[Inside tap](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L690):

```
VALUE
rb_obj_tap(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_yield(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Can be useful for:

- grouping side effects together
- chain/pipe functions
- reduce the use of intermediate variables
- easier to work with a nested hashes

To summarise, more "functional" style